# mongo shell not allowing anything to be typed

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have installed mongodb and created the C:/data/db folder. Inside C:/mongodb/bin/ I successfully ran >mongod in a terminal, and in another I ran >mongo.
However, the second terminal >mongo command does not work.

[Screenshort of Terminal >mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJI0s.png)

Running >mongo will show the output below, but I cannot type anything. Anyone know what is going on?

```
C:\mongo\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
```

Comment: mongod is not running

Comment: I restarted my computer and tried it again and it worked! :)